# SQL Foreign Key

Tags: sql, key

Во время проектирования базы столкнулся с тем что мне нужно заполнять таблицу используя внешний ключ, но и иметь возможность вносить в это поле данные которых нет во родительской таблице.
Как это реализовать?

Comment: Вносить данные сначала в родительскую таблицу, ну или избавиться от внешнего ключа.

Comment: 1) спросить у владельца другой базы, чтоб он триггер какой сделал 2) изобрести телепортер...

Answer (score 2):

@Mirdin - Вносить данные сначала в родительскую таблицу, ну или избавиться от внешнего ключа.Лучше и нe скажешь.
Или записывать туда NULL,если он nulable by default,что он - MySQL и так делаeт ecли в него ничего нe записывать

Answer (score 1):

Из первой таблицы удалите поле с внешним ключом. Создайте третью таблицу связки этих двух таблиц с составным первичным ключом `table3 (table1_id, table2_id)`

Если связка с внешним ID есть - в третью таблицу добавляете запись, если нет - то не добавляете.

Выборка вида

```
SELECT t1.*, t3.table2_id FROM table1 t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.id = t3.table1_id
```

даст результат, в котором Вы получите пустые значения для кортежей, с пустым внешним ключем и заполненные значения для кортежей со связкой